# display ids of all values of a particular column is NA r

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, lapply

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5)
val1 <-c(NA,1,2,NA,NA,3,4,4,NA,NA)
dt <- data.frame(id,val1)
```

dt being my dataframe i want to output the id which has all val1 as NA.

```
id val1
1  NA
1  1
1  2
2  NA
3  NA
3  NA
3  3
4  4
4  4
5  NA
5  NA
```

output should be

```
id
2
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can do with `dplry` package

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(is.na(val1))) %>%
  pull(id) %>%
  unique()
```

**output**:

```
[1] 2 5
```

Comment: I noticed you suggested an edit to the question that tried to fix something. You should include that information in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'id', `filter` the rows that have all `NA` in 'val1' and `select` the 'id' column

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     filter(all(is.na(val1))) %>%
     select(id) %>%
     distinct
# A tibble: 2 x 1
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id
#  <dbl>
#1     2
#2     5
```